# jQuery Countdown plugin and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, countdownlatch

I'm using [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) to implement a Countdown and call a webservice when timer expires.

The problem is that I'm using AJAX on the page, and have to re-setup the Countdown on every AJAX request like so:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(SetupTimer);

/*Initial setup*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    SetupTimer();
});

function SetupTimer() {
        var serverTime = new Date();
        var cutoffTime = new Date($("#<%= cutoffTime.ClientID %>").val());
        serverTime.setHours(serverTime.getHours());
        if (serverTime < cutoffTime) {
            $('#timer').countdown('destroy'); /*should work, but doesn't*/
            $('#timer').countdown({ until: cutoffTime, serverTime: serverTime, onExpiry: OrderingEnded, format: 'yowdHMS' });
        } 
        else
            OrderingEnded();
    }
```

This, for some reason, creates a new instance of the Countdown on ever request, resulting in numerous calls to Webservice when Countdown expires.

**How do I make sure that only one instance of the Countdown exists at a time?**

#### EDIT

found this in documentation, doesn't do it for me though

```
        $('#timer').countdown('destroy');
```

Comment: the link to the plugin doesn't work

Comment: Looks like something that's fancy that isn't getting you anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, figured it out, just needed to call the

```
$('#timer').countdown('destroy');
```

on beginRequest

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(DeleteTimer);
prm.add_endRequest(SetupTimer);

$(document).ready(function() {
    SetupTimer();
});


function DeleteTimer() {
    $('#timer').countdown('destroy');
}
function SetupTimer() {
    var serverTime = new Date();
    var cutoffTime = new Date($("#<%= cutoffTime.ClientID %>").val());
    serverTime.setHours(serverTime.getHours());
    if (serverTime < cutoffTime) {          
        $('#timer').countdown({ until: cutoffTime, serverTime: serverTime, onExpiry: OrderingEnded, format: 'yowdHMS' });
    } 
    else
        OrderingEnded();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `setInterval()`. It allows you to repeat the timer every X milliseconds. You can use `clearInterval()` to stop it.

[Here is some reading](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-using-setinterval-and-settimeout) comparing `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`.

Another option to only recreate the timer in the callback function of the AJAX call. This will ensure a new timer is only started once the previous AJAX call is complete, such as:

```
 function CheckServer() {
     $.get('/get_something.html', function() {
         timer = setTimeout('CheckServer', 5000);
     });
 }
```

Comment: i don't care about the timer functionality, plugin does all that, i just need to know how to make sure it only has ONE INSTANCE running

Comment: i reworded the question, i guess it was a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar type of problem. I am using web services to get the current time from the server using serversync function in jquery.countdown.js plugin. I have a facing a problem

[How countdown get Synchronise with jquery using "jquery.countdown.js" plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609028/how-countdown-get-synchronise-with-jquery-using-jquery-countdown-js-plugin)

will you please find the solution and let me know thanks.

Comment: why don't you use my solution?