# How countdown get Synchronise with jquery using "jquery.countdown.js" plugin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Unable to get the correct Ans as i am getting correct result from the Jquery variable "shortly" but when i am Synchronise with function "serverSync" all will set to 0:0:0 i have checked both having a same date.
ref. site
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

here is my code

```
[WebMethod]
public static String GetTime()
{
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
    dt = Convert.ToDateTime("April 9, 2010 22:38:10");  
    return dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var shortly = new Date('April 9, 2010 22:38:10');
        var newTime = new Date('April 9, 2010 22:38:10');
        //for loop divid
        /// 
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
            until: shortly, onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown, serverSync: serverTime
        });
        $('#div1').countdown({ until: newTime });
    });

    function serverTime() {
        var time = null;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //Page Name (in which the method should be called) and method name
            url: "Default.aspx/GetTime",
            // If you want to pass parameter or data to server side function you can try line
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            async: false,
            //else If you don't want to pass any value to server side function leave the data to blank line below
            //data: "{}",  
            success: function(msg) {
                //Got the response from server and render to the client

                time = new Date(msg.d);
                alert(time);
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                time = new Date();
                alert('1');
            }
        });

        return time;

    }
    function watchCountdown() { }
    function liftOff() { }

</script>
```

Comment: If you take the countdown plugin out of the picture, is your Webmethod returning a value at all?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608838/having-problem-with-jquery-countdown-function-serversync-servertime and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608389/unable-to-get-a-correct-time-when-i-am-calling-servertime-using-jquery-countdown

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the server time equal to the time you're counting down towards.

Since the new "serverSync" time and the "until" time are the same, the countdown will just be 0's across the board.

Comment: Thanks Doc hoffiday

But the problem i set the "shortly" variable and "serverSync" returning the same date. shortly date working fine, but "serverSync" display 0's accross the board

I need to run the countdown that will be coming from the "serverSync" function.